# Facebook API : Can't get number of Facebook likes on an online server

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of likes of a Facebook account with this PHP line :

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?fields=likes');
```

This work on my local server. The problem is this doesn't seems to work on an online server (var_dump($content) return the value "false").

I don't really quite understand why this works only in my local server. Did someone already encounter this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible your hosting doesn't support file_get_contents. Check `allow_url_fopen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider switching to curl, it's much better for interacting with APIs.

```
$postData = http_build_query(
    [
        'fields' => 'likes'
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init();

$endpoint = sprintf('%s?%s', 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook', $postData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```